# Any way to fix screen lines/flicker on Ubuntu 20 with a Mobility Radeon HD 3400 series gpu

Tags: graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, 20.04

I've been trying to install ubuntu 20 on my Toshiba A300 laptop but i'm getting a weird line/flicker effect on a fresh install of ubuntu 20 (also had the same issue with 18) shown below, it's the visible diagonal lines and they move across the screen has anyone came across this and know of a fix?

[image: diagonal lines effect]

I've tried setting various combinations of the boot options below but had no success

```
nolapic
noapic
acpi=off
pnpacpi=off
radeon.dpm=0
```

The only solution that removes the lines is using `nomodeset` which causes a lower resolution to be used and from what i understand will cause a default driver to be used instead of the radeon driver which mean graphics acceleration will be off as well, so not really ideal.

I also tried out Fedora 31 which also has the same problem which make me think possibly this is an issue with the open source radeon driver but i can't find anything in the log files to indicate if that is the case.

I currently have ubuntu 16 installed as both 18 & 20 have this problem however i captured the logs & output below from the live disk of ubuntu 20.

#### uname -a

```
Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 20 16:58:30 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

#### lspci -vvvnn (just the gpu)

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV620/M82 [Mobility Radeon HD 3450/3470] [1002:95c4] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Toshiba Corporation RV620/M82 [Mobility Radeon HD 3450/3470] [1179:ff50]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 30
    Region 0: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 2: Memory at f0200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [58] Express (v2) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
        LnkCtl: ASPM L0s L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s (ok), Width x16 (ok)
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis-, NROPrPrP-, LTR-
             10BitTagComp-, 10BitTagReq-, OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt-, EETLPPrefix-
             EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
             FRS-
             AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
             AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee01004  Data: 4029
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

Output from `modinfo radeon` [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/FUGmGsjR) and dmesg.log [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/bY3CLNSb) which does contain some acpi errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else coming across this issue the solution is to compile your own kernel with the patch from https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/dri-devel/2020-August/277528.html (shown below) which still works on kernel 5.19.0-43 (tested on ubuntu 22)

```
---
 drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_display.c | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

diff --git a/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_display.c b/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_display.c
index e0ae911ef427..7b69d6dfe44a 100644
--- a/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_display.c
+++ b/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_display.c
@@ -933,7 +933,7 @@ static void avivo_get_fb_ref_div(unsigned nom, unsigned den, unsigned post_div,
 
    /* get matching reference and feedback divider */
    *ref_div = min(max(den/post_div, 1u), ref_div_max);
-   *fb_div = DIV_ROUND_CLOSEST(nom * *ref_div * post_div, den);
+   *fb_div = max(nom * *ref_div * post_div / den, 1u);
 
    /* limit fb divider to its maximum */
    if (*fb_div > fb_div_max) {
--
```

there was also a bug ticket for this issue but it seems to have gone nowhere https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1861554